# Sign out not working properly in OpenID Connect

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I have integrated OpenID Connect(Generic), where my Signin was successful(Redirects to destination server, provided credentials, redirect to drupal & authenticated).

While i make Sign out, it was successful. But what i found is, log out happens only at drupal side whereas my destined server session still exists(I have checked it by relogin in drupal, it was authenticated without providing credentials).

[image]

Is there is any option to log out from both Drupal & destined server?

Answer (score 2):

The openid_connect module is great for authenticating/adding users via external identity providers. However, it does not provide single sign out capabilities.

You will have to implement them yourself.

A viable way of doing so is to implement `hook_openid_connect_post_authorize()` to add information about the used identity provider/tokens to the user session/database, and e.g. [hook_user_logout()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/7.x) to invoking the sign-out endpoint of your identity provider, if the above saved information is present when the user logs off your Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Is this still the way to go? I just started using this module and have the same problem as mentioned. In `admin/config/people/openid-connect/settings` i can see a checkbox with label `Logout from identity provider` and description `If enabled and supported by the identity provider, logging out from Drupal will also logout the user from the identity provider.` But i does not work in my case using a generic client with AWS Cognito